# I can't send object from server to client

Tags: java, mysql, defaulttablemodel

While trying to get a table from the server, I get:

> java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00

And

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set a null TableModel

**Why does that happen and how do I fix it?**

Here is my client class where I write functions:

```
public class Client {

    private Socket client;
    private DataInputStream dis;
    private DataOutputStream dos;
    private ObjectInputStream ois;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos;



    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;



    public void setClientInfo(int id, String name, String surname) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void connectServer() {
        try {

            client = new Socket("localhost", 3000);
            dis = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            dos = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());



            System.out.println("I/O streams for client created");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void closeConnection() {
        try {
            sendUTFDataToServer("EXIT");
            dis.close();
            dos.close();
            client.close();
            System.out.println("CLIENT END");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean sendUTFDataToServer(String msg) {

        if (client != null) {
            try {
                dos.writeUTF(msg);
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean sendIntDataToServer(int num) {

        if (client != null) {
            try {
                dos.writeInt(num);
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean sendDoubleDataToServer(double num) {

        if (client != null) {
            try {
                dos.writeDouble(num);
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getUTFDataFromServer() {
        String res = "";
        if (client != null) {
            try {
                res = dis.readUTF();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public int getIntDataFromServer() {
        int res = 0;
        if (client != null) {
            try {
                res = dis.readInt();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public double getDoubleDataFromServer() {
        double res = 0;
        if (client != null) {
            try {
                res = dis.readDouble();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public void sendObjectToServer(Object obj) {

        if (client != null) {
            try {
                oos.writeObject(obj);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public Object getObjectFromServer() {
        Object obj = null;
        if (client != null) {
            try {

                obj = (DefaultTableModel) ois.readObject();

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
    public DefaultTableModel showBook(){
        DefaultTableModel dtm=null;
        try {
            dos.writeUTF("showbooks");

            dtm = (DefaultTableModel) ois.readObject();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dtm;
    }
    public String addBook(int id,String author,String name,int library_id)
    {
        String mes="";
        try {
            dos.writeUTF("ADD");
            dos.writeInt(id);
            dos.writeUTF(author);
            dos.writeUTF(name);
            dos.writeInt(library_id);

            mes =dis.readUTF();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return mes;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client=new Client();
        client.connectServer();
        Login_Frame frame = new Login_Frame(client);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Here is my server class;

```
public class Server {

    private int port = 3000;
    private ServerSocket server;
    public static int count = 0;
    public static int activeClientCount = 0;

    public Server() {

        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server Started");

            DB.initializeDB();
            System.out.println("Database Connection established");

            while (true) {
                System.out
                        .println("Server: Server is waiting for client connetion");
                Socket clientSocket = server.accept();
                count++;
                activeClientCount++;

                System.out.println("Server: Client connection is provided "
                        + count);
                System.out.println("Active Client  " + activeClientCount);

                MyClientThread mt = new MyClientThread(clientSocket);
                mt.start();
            }

        }  catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("END SERVER");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();
    }

    class MyClientThread extends Thread {


        DataInputStream dis;
        DataOutputStream dos;

        ObjectInputStream ois;
        ObjectOutputStream oos;

        Socket clientsocket;
        public MyClientThread(Socket csocket) {
            this.clientsocket = csocket;
            System.out.println("Client connected");
            try {
                dis = new DataInputStream(clientsocket.getInputStream());
                dos = new DataOutputStream(clientsocket.getOutputStream());

                ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientsocket.getInputStream());
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientsocket.getOutputStream());



                System.out.println("I/O streams are created");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                while (true && clientsocket != null) {

                    System.out.println("waiting for opp command");
                    String opp = dis.readUTF();

                    String res = "";

                    if (opp.equals("LOGIN")) {

                        String un = dis.readUTF();
                        String pw = dis.readUTF();
                        String type=dis.readUTF();

                        ResultSet rs = ServerSys.login(un, pw,type);


                        if(rs.next()==false)
                        {
                            dos.writeUTF("nouser");

                        }
                        else
                        {
                                dos.writeUTF("YES");
                                dos.writeInt(rs.getInt(1));
                                dos.writeUTF(rs.getString(2));
                                dos.writeUTF(rs.getString(3));      

                        }

                        }
                    else if(opp.equals("showbooks"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("book'a girdi");
                        dos.writeUTF("YES");
                        dos.writeUTF("HEllo");
                        ResultSet rs=DB.executeQ("select * from book");

                        DefaultTableModel dtm= DB.showTables(rs);
                        System.out.println(dtm.getValueAt(1,1));
                        oos.writeObject(dtm);


                    }


                    }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and server_function class;

```
public class ServerSys {
    public static ResultSet login(String un, String pw,String type) {
        String sql="";
        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("client"))
        {   
            sql = "select * from client where clientName ='" + un
                    + "' and clientPass='" + pw + "'";

        }
        else
        {
            sql = "select * from admin where adminName ='" + un
                    + "' and adminPassword='" + pw + "'";
        }


        ResultSet rs = DB.executeQ(sql);
        return rs;

    }

    public static void insertBook(int id,String bookauthor,String name,int libraryid) {
        String sql = "insert into book values(" + id + ",'" + bookauthor + "',"+libraryid+
                 ")";
        try {
            DB.executeQ(sql);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

                }

    public static DefaultTableModel showTable(String sql){
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();        
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            rs = DB.executeQ(sql);

            ResultSetMetaData rsmd= (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();
            Vector header= new Vector();
            Vector datarows = new Vector();

            int columnumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            for(int i=1; i<columnumber; i++){
                header.add(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
            }

            while(rs.next()){
                Vector row=new Vector();
                for(int i=1; i<columnumber; i++){
                    row.add(rs.getObject(i));
                }               
                datarows.add(row);
            }
            dtm.setDataVector(datarows, header);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return dtm;

    }

}
```

By the way I can send for example string array with objectoutputstream so I guess problem is only with defaulttablemodel.

Comment: `While trying to get a table from the server, I get:`. Well which code is causing that?

Answer (score 0):

I see in your code:

```
        dis = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        dos = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
```

I don't think you should do that: you have two different high level streams writing or reading in the same low level stream. Depending on how they buffer data, that will end in disaster. Just use the ObjectOutputStream, since an ObjectOutputStream implements DataOutput, you can write primitives from it too. So just get rid of dis and dos.

Comment: Any change to do it in this way?